# Perl regular expression to match numerics

Tags: regex, perl

Need to match BSC0 to BSC10 and "TOTAL". But the below condition is matching only BSC1 and BSC10. Whats missing? tried with `s/regex/` `m/regex/` variations also

`$currentRowHeader` will contain single word without spaces

```
if ($currentRowHeader =~ /BSC[0-10]|TOTAL/) { print "OK"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[...]` is a *character* class. It can match only a single character. Regular expressions have no concepts of numbers - only of digit characters. What your regex is saying is

> Match a character from `0` to `1` (that is `0` *or* `1`) or match a `0`.

So it only matches one binary digit. You could use

```
if ($currentRowHeader =~ /BSC(?:[0-9]|10)|TOTAL/) { print "OK" }
```

Note that the `?:` is not necessary but is a good habit, as it suppresses unnecessary [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and hence speeds up the operation.

Answer (score 2):

The dash in a character class is a range of *characters*, not *values*. Try this:

```
if ($currentRowHeader =~ /BSC(10|\d)|TOTAL/)
```

FYI `\d` means "any digit" and is identical (with Latin characters) to coding `[0-9]`, but shorter and easier to read.

As some pedants will tell you, `\d` includes non-Latin numbers like Arabic and Chinese symbols for numbers, but that is clearly irrelevant in the context of this question.

Comment: Please don't further the myth that `\d` == `[0-9]` While this is true for many cases (the string only contains ASCII chars, the `/a` modifier is in effect, etc), it actually matches any character that is considered a digit by Unicode. E.g. this Arabic digit ٤: `perl -Mutf8 -E'say "٤" =~ /\d/ ? "yes":"no"'`

Comment: @amon sure, but in the context of this question, which clearly uses English numbers, what I said is true. Also, \d is very widely used in this way. I would be totally comfortable going to production with this regex.